# Чи можна дієслово "топати" вживати як синонім до "іти" для позначення ходи малюків?

Tags: синоніми, дієслова

Чомусь вважала, що дієслово **`топати`** походить від звуконаслідування **`топ-топ`**, є синонімом **`іти`** та позначає ходу малюків, що роблять свої перші кроки.

Утім, [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/topaty) не наводить прикладів саме в такому значенні:

> **ТОПАТИ**, аю, аєш, недок., звичайно наказ. сп., розм., рідко. Іти. [Клеопатра:] Топай, стара баржо, подертий парус! [Барабаш:] Іду,
>   іду... (Олександр Корнійчук, Чому посміх. зорі, 1958, 81); [Шметелюк:]
>   Та йди ти зі своїм ходом до чорта! Я через тебе на Чайченка спізнюсь.
>   Забирай свої шахи і топай скоріш!.. (Іван Микитенко, I, 1957, 204); —
>   Хто йде?.. — Та це я. Свої. Фігура в сірячині з гвинтівкою «на руку»
>   ближче підійшла до тебе і впилася очима. — А — ти? Утік? Ну, топай же
>   в яр. Наші там (Андрій Головко, I, 1957, 75).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 10, 1979. — Стор. 194.

Подумалось, що схоже значення може мати **`дріботіти`**, але наведені приклади у відповідній статті [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/dribotity), хоч і містять значення для дитини, але неоднозначно, що саме для перших кроків малечі, та й інші цитати підтверджують ширший діапазон значень:

> **ДРІБОТІТИ**, очу, оти́ш і **ДРІБОТАТИ**, очу, очеш, недок., розм.
>
> 1. Швидко перебираючи ногами, йти дрібними частими кроками; тюпати. Підгодовані коники хутенько дріботіли ніжками по уторованому шляху, що
>      вився понад річкою (Олесь Досвітній, Вибр., 1959, 42); Плавно дибав
>      каліка на ..милицях, а за калікою дріботить босими ніжками дитина
>      (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 33); Катерина, дрібочучи босими ногами
>      по гострому камінні, ледве-ледве встигала за ним (Степан Чорнобривець,
>      Визволена земля, 1950, 96);  //  Танцювати, часто перебираючи та
>      пристукуючи ногами. Одарка не втерпіла й пішла дріботіти козачка
>      (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 66).
> 2. Часто й ритмічно вдаряючи по чому-небудь, створювати відповідні звуки. Дріботів у шибки осінній дощ (Натан Рибак, Опов., 1949, 13);
>      Іде громохко поїзд під уклін і дріботять колеса над мостами (Сава
>      Голованівський, Поезії, 1955, 217); Осколки дріботять та риють землю
>      довкола... (Юрій Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 154).
> 3. Говорити дуже швидко, скоромовкою. — Кажу тобі, — витратився й витрусився до останньої гривні, ні шага за душею нема: хоч в домовину
>      лягай, — дріботів дід Грицай (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 205).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 2, 1971. — Стор. 416.

[Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53383/266002.html), цитуючи словник синонімів Караванського, взагалі не включає ні `топати`, ні `дріботіти` до синонімічного ряду дієслова `іти`:

> **ІТИ**  йти, ходити, ступати, простувати, прямувати, крокувати, ф. тупати, чимчикувати, ур. спрямовувати свої стопи; (у бій) рушати;
>   (тривалий час) бродити, брести, блукати; (повільно) плентатися; (через
>   силу) волоктися, чвалати, чалапати, клигати, чапати; (як на дибах)
>   дибати; (енергійно) чухрати, манджати; (далеко) тарабанитися; (без
>   діла) віятися; ФР. виходити, надходити, заходити, підходити, рухатися;
>   (на що) пускатися; (з рук до рук) переходити, передаватися; (в отвір)
>   проходити; (- пошту) пересилатися; (за кого) виходити заміж; (- літа)
>   минати; (- природне явище) наближатися, насуватися; (- життя)
>   розвивати-. с

**Тож чи можна вживати дієслово `топати` для позначення ходи малечі, яка робить свої перші кроки, чи є вдаліший відповідник?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мені ще не доводилося чути, щоб вживали слово "топати" для позначення ходи малечі, але в Інтернеті є приклади такого вживання (щоправда там зазвичай пишуть "**топати ніжками**"). Наприклад:

> На мою посмішку його очі починають сяяти від щастя, він намагається
>   "агукати" мені у відповідь, дуже любить топати ніжками з підтримкою за
>   ручки. ([сторінка Фейсбук](https://www.facebook.com/ubb.org.ua/posts/%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD-%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%94-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE-/2183140435044750/))
>
> Зараз у свої неповні три рочки дитина завдяки постійним реабілітаціям
>   стала вимовляти звуки і топати ніжками. ([сайт ТСН](https://tsn.ua/dopomoga/batki-sofiyki-prosyat-dopomogi-v-likuvannya-donki-971297.html))

Гадаю, що іменник "ніжками" тут не просто так додали, а він, немов, натякає, що ноги ще маленькі, а відповідно вислів "топати ніжками" означатиме "ходу малої дитини" (однак, це лише моя теорія).

Крім того, знаю схоже слово "**тупцювати**". Є воно і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/tupcjuvaty) і якщо ми подивимося на приклад до одного із його значень:

> Малим ще, тямую, всі межі я знав. За мамою літом щодень **тупцював**
>   (Іван Франко, X, 1954, 178);

Тобто тут цим слово також описується хода малої дитини. А якщо глянемо на схоже слово "**тупцяти**" ([словник Грінченка](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)), то серед ілюстрацій можна побачити фото малої дитини, яка кудись іде. Та й, можлвио, про дитячу ходьбу ідеться в прикладі:

Він часто по баб’ячій **тупцяв** по хаті.

І ще може підійти слово "[**чимчикувати**](http://sum.in.ua/s/chymchykuvaty)". Одне з його значень:

> Іти швидко, поспішно, часто ступаючи

І якщо ви звертали увагу, то малі діти саме так і ходять, а тому це також може бути хорошим варіантом. Бачимо, що всі наведені мною приклади є [синонімами](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8).